# Leave parts of the instructions blank for python to complete

Tags: python, list, if-statement, generalization

I'm new to Python so I don't know if this is possible, but my guess is yes. I want to iterate over a list and put items into new lists according to their value. For instance, if `item_x == 4`, I would want to put it in a list called `list_for_4`. The same is true for all other items in my list and numbers 0 to 10. So is it possible to generalize a statement in such a way that if `item_x == *a certain value*`, it will be appended to `list_for_*a certain value*`?
Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do this instead of, say, use a `dict`?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to [create a variable number of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use list comprehension with if statement inside?

Like:

```
list_for_4 = [x for x in my_list if x==4]
```

And combine it with a dict.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to generate a dynamic variables. A map using a dictionary structure might help you.

For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
item_list = [1, 2, 3, 9, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]

# Use a dictionary which elements are a list by default:
items_map = defaultdict(list)

for i in item_list:
    items_map['list_for_{}'.format(i)].append(i)
print(items_map)

#  Test the map for elements in the list:
if 'list_for_4' in items_map:
    print(items_map['list_for_4'])
else:
    print('`list_for_4` not found.')
```

Alternatively if you only require the number of times an item occurs in the list you could aggregate it using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
item_list = [1, 2, 3, 9, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
result = Counter(item_list)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

With a simple iteration  through the list:

```
lst_for_1 = []
lst_for_2 = []
lst_for_3 = []
d = {1: lst_for_1, 2: lst_for_2, 3: lst_for_3}
for x in lst:
    d[x].append(x)
```

Or, if you want a condition that is more complicated than just the value of x, define a function:

```
def f(x):
  if some condition...:
     return lst_for_1
  elif some other condition:
     return lst_for_2
  else:
     return lst_for_3
```

Then replace `d[x].append(x)` by `f(x).append(x)`.

If you don't want to do the iteration yourself, you could also use map:

```
list(map(lambda x: d[x].append(x),lst))
```

or

```
list(map(lambda x: f(x).append(x),lst))
```

The version with map will return an list of `Nones` that you don't care about. `map(...)` returns an iterator, and as long as you do not iterate through it (for example, to turn its result into a list), it will not perform the mapping. That's why you need the `list(map(...))`, it will create a dummy list but append the items of `lst` to the right lists on the way, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you want to do it. But you can do it.

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5]

for item in data:
    name = f'list_for_{item}'
    if name in globals():
        globals()[name].append(item)
    else:
        globals()[name] = [item]
```